# PrintMe is never used locally

Tags: java

I think that solution to my problem is simple, but I'm a beginner and can't figure it out. I got error "method is never use locally" for methods printMe, removeStuff, reverseMe.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test1 
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        String[] rzeczy = {"afriso", "danfoss", "honeywell", "gorgiel", 
"sanha"};
        List<String> list1 = new LinkedList<String>();
        for(String x: rzeczy)   
            list1.add(x);

        String[] rzeczy2 = {"akces", "afriso", "dedietrich"};
        List<String> list2 = new LinkedList<String>();
        for(String y: rzeczy2)
            list2.add(y);

        list1.addAll(list2);
        list2 = null;
    }

    private static void printMe (List<String> l)
    {
        for(String b : l)
            System.out.printf("%s ", b);
        System.out.println();
    }
    private static void removeStuff (List<String> l, int from, int to)
    {
        l.subList(from, to).clear();
    }
    private static void reverseMe (List<String> l)
    {
        ListIterator<String> bobby= l.listIterator(l.size());
        while(bobby.hasPrevious())
            System.out.printf("%s ", bobby.previous());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use these methods?

Comment: You get that message because you never use those methods.  Why did you write them if you don't ever call them?

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time, i misunderstood how to use it. I add lines as below and it's working.
                printMe(list1);
  removeStuff(list1, 2,5);
  printMe(list1);
  reverseMe(list1);

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the error, use the methods somewhere. Java is telling you that these methods haven't ever been used and are as good as if they aren't even there.
Also, this shouldn't even be an error in the console, only in the actual code.